# How to get index of selected object?

Tags: javascript

I need index of employee object to perform update operation in angularjs. I am using $routeParams & sending parameter (i.e. /employee/:guid) and receiving it as  `var guid = $routeParams.guid;` . Then  i needed index to get my employee object here. so i have written function to get index like :

```
function getSelectedIndex(guid){
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.employees.length; i++){
        if($scope.employees[i].guid==guid)
            return i;
        return -1;
    }
};
```

This function is not working if i choose employee having `index>0`. If anybody knows better way to solve this scene, please help me!!

Comment: Always use curly braces, and tell your editor to indent your code, and you'll find the problem. When do youknow you must return -1? After you've checked the first element, or after you've checked them all? Also, learn to use a debugger. Problems like this are trivial to find out by stepping through the code line by line. Finally, this has nothing to do with AngularJS, and even less with Java. Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: how about an angularjs tag?

Comment: I wanted to get employee object from employees array using index like **var employee=$scope.employees[index]** then i'm performing further operation. So can you tell me how do i get index?????plzzz

Comment: @tharanga-dinesh thanks, I found my mistake. Actually i wanted to return -1 if none of then match, but here i am returning -1 after checking first element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function getSelectedIndex(guid){
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.employees.length; i++){
        if($scope.employees[i].guid==guid){
            return i;
        }
     }
     return -1; 
};
```

Comment: @TanajiKolekar if this is the answer you were looking for, please accept answer because maybe someday, someone will be looking for same answer as you

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your original function is you are returning after the first iteration of the `for` loop whether the `if` matches or not.

But I would just use [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) — it's simpler and easier to read:

```js
let employees = [
    {guid: 10, name: "Mark"},
    {guid: 12, name: "Joe"},
    {guid: 13, name: "Beth"},
    {guid: 14, name: "Steve"}
]
let guid = 13
let index = employees.findIndex(emp => emp.guid === guid)
console.log(index)
console.log(employees[index])
```

Comment: This one is also worked for me. But can you explain me how this line works **var index = employees.findIndex(emp => emp.guid === guid)** .

Comment: @TanajiKolekar `findIndex` expects a function that returns a boolean it will return the index of the first element where that function returns `true`. `emp => emp.guid === guid` is a function that takes an object (`emp`) and returns a boolean `emp.guid === guid`. So for each element `findIndex` calls this function until it finds a matching guid.

Comment: thanks i understand. Which approach is better ? should i go with yours or mine?

Comment: I think that's a matter of opinion @TanajiKolekar. My opinion is that this is more succinct and easier to just look at and know what it does. Also it's a built-in function, so it seems like less work than making a new function that does the same thing. It's possible, however, that the `for` loop is faster because of JS engine optimizations - although maybe not by much.